# Guy returns home to find time has lapsed by 17 years

Tags: identify-this-movie

The beginning of the movie shows a scene where a boy goes out to play, only to return home and find that time has lapsed by more than 17 years.

It *might* have something to do with time travel.

Which movie is this?

Comment: Sounds similar to [Flight Of The Navigator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator) but that was only 8 years.

Comment: The boy goes out to find his brother. Trips falling into a ravine and wakes up later. He returns home to find 8 years has past. Watch it to see why. Great movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are talking about the movie "Flight of the Navigator": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator

It involves space travel at light speed and therefore time travel.

Although only 8 years are passed in this movie when he returns.